# Why is mockito's when().thenReturn() not working?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am testing `JdbcSpitterDao#getSpitterByid()` and am mocking `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()`

```
public class JdbcSpitterDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements SpitterDao {
...
    public Spitter getSpitterById(long id,
            ParameterizedRowMapper<Spitter> parameterizedRowMapper) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_SELECT_SPITTER,
                parameterizedRowMapper, id);
    }
...
}
```

My test object contains the following

```
    ParameterizedRowMapper<Spitter> parameterizedRowMapper = new ParameterizedRowMapper<Spitter>() {
        public Spitter mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Spitter Spitter = new Spitter();
            spitter.setId(rs.getLong(1));
            spitter.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
            spitter.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
            spitter.setFullName(rs.getString(4));
            spitter.setEmail(rs.getString(5));
            return spitter;
        }
    };
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    JdbcSpitterDao jdbcSpitterDao = new JdbcSpitterDao();   
    jdbcSpitterDao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

    // Don't connect to the database.  Mock JdbcTemplate class
    when(
            jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    JdbcSpitterDao.SQL_SELECT_SPITTER,
                    parameterizedRowMapper, 1)).thenReturn(new Spitter(1, "rajkumarm", "rajmukarm",
                            "Rajkumar Masaniayan", "rajkumarm@gmail.com"));

    // Actual test
    Spitter actualSpitter = jdbcSpitterDao.getSpitterById(1, parameterizedRowMapper);
```

But `when().thenReturn()` idiom is not getting invoked.  The control is flowing to actual `jdbcTemplate`.  Looks like there is a problem with

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
```

or

```
jdbcSpitterDao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
```

Would you please let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't understand, half the code uses `JdbcSpitterDao` and half uses `JdbcTwitterDao`. Is that just a really persistent typo, or do you have different types? That could certainly cause the issue you're seeing if they're different classes.

Comment: :-).  It is really persistent typo.  Was changing the name type manually in Stackoverflow

Comment: Have you added an assert at the end, to check the result?

Comment: Apparently mockito has an issue with anonymous objects.  It is expecting the object used in the actual function invocation to be provided to when().thenReturn() idiom as well.  I got this working by creating an Impl class for parameterizedRowMapper<T> interface and using the same function at both the places.

Comment: You should add this as an answer, and then accept it. Just so others can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is this suggestion not to mock the types you don't own. In general it is a good suggestion and here it really makes sense not to unit test that dao at all. Why not just integration test sth which operates on DB and does no additional logic?